# MySql: Compare 2 strings which are numbers?

Tags: mysql, comparison

I have a column in my table, it holds values such as 100012345. The column is varchar. Now I want to compare this to similiar values in a where:

```
... where myColumn > '100012345'
```

for example. How could I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Cast your string to the appropriate type (whatever type myColumn is). See [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: if both values are varchar, you don't have to cast them. Even if they are not, mysql should compare them properly anyway. select 123='123'; returns true for example but it might depend on your mysql config.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
where cast(your_column as signed) = 100012345
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to do it normally, like this:

```
... where myColumn > 100012345
```

That **should work!**, mysql automatically casts a string to number when it's in the context of a number operation. In the same way it casts a number to string if it's used in a string context. See the examples in the [**type conversion docs**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html):

To cast a string to a numeric value in numeric context, you normally do not have to do anything other than to use the string value as though it were a number:

```
mysql> SELECT 1+'1';
       -> 2
```

If you use a string in an arithmetic operation, it is converted to a floating-point number during expression evaluation.

If you use a number in string context, the number automatically is converted to a string:

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT('hello you ',2);
        -> 'hello you 2'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [cast the value](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) to an integer:

`CAST(myColumn AS INTEGER)`

Comment: Your code is not working, you linked the documentation of CAST function but instead used syntax of CONVERT function

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to cast strings into integers to compare, mysql does it automatically.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html

Comment: But if you want to e.g. get the max numeric value of a string column, you need to do e.g. SELECT MAX(the_value + 0), otherwise '99.0' is larger then '750'.

Answer (score 1):

If your column field is of type varchar then you have to Cast the columns you want to compare else mysql will treat a value like 20 to be greater than 100000.You can do that by using the inbuilt [cast](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) function

```
select * from your_table
where cast(your_column as signed) > 100012345
```

You can also do

```
select * from your_table
    where 'your_column+0' > '100012345+0'
```

Mysql will add your string number to zero and then cast them as an integer

If your column field is of type INT then you can do the normal comparism

```
select * from your_table
where your_column > 100012345
```

N/B it is always appropriate to use the correct column types esp. when you know the value the column is expecting