# Compare strings as numbers

Tags: mysql, select, casting, min

I have some prices in a MySQL db, written like:

```
19900
29900
30000
28900
etc.
```

How can I compare these as numbers, so I can use MIN (price) correctly in my SELECT queries?

I have found [MySql: Compare 2 strings which are numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749219/mysql-compare-2-strings-which-are-numbers), but it looks like I can't nest the MIN and the CAST correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960620/convert-text-into-number-in-mysql-query) helpful

Try [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d444/4) sql fiddle!

or
try this:

```
SELECT min(CONVERT(price,UNSIGNED INTEGER)) AS num
FROM sample
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `cast` expression inside `min`:

```
SELECT MIN (CAST mycolumn AS signed)
FROM   my_table
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's exactly what I have tried. And then I get this error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'price AS signed), image FROM masterproducts m, shopproducts s' at line 1

Price field is a varchar

Query: SELECT name, MIN(price AS SIGNED), image FROM masterproducts m, shopproducts s WHERE m.name = s.mastername

Comment: You're missing the `cast` key-word before `price`.

Comment: Didn't help (the CAST keyword was there, it's just me who missed it when typing things here...)